# Jmeter java.rmi.ConnectException

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have 2 Virtual Machines(Ubuntu), the first 1 as Master, and the second as slave, when I run the test on the Remote Machine I got the following:

Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.56.10; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

VirtualBox: 6.0

VirtualMachine:Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan Ermine

Apache Jmeter: 5.2.1

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure to have [bridged networking mode](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) for both VMs so each VM would have it's own IP address assigned
2. On master machine add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter):

   ```
   remote_hosts=ip address of the slave machine here
   ```
3. Make sure that [Ubuntu firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html) is either disabled or following ports are allowed there

   - 1099 (or the port you define as `server_port`)
   - the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
   - the port(s) you define as  `client.rmi.localport`
4. If not yet, follow instructions from the [Setting up SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) chapter or disable secure communication between master and slave(s) by adding the next line to *user.properties* file on both nodes:

   ```
   server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
   ```

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)